# Android:High Quality Facebook Profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to show the facebook friends profile picture in my app.

I used this URL
http://graph.facebook.com/uid/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=600&height=600

I'm getting the image in web browser but its not loading in android app.The issue is not with the imageview,since I checked another image URL it gets appeared in imageview.

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(http://graph.facebook.com/uid/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=600&height=600, thumb_image);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link that you provide will give you high clarity image.the problem that happened the link you call you are using http, use https like this:

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(https://graph.facebook.com/uid/picture?type=large&redirect=true&width=600&height=600, thumb_image);
```